# Utilizing bluetooth LE on Raspberry Pi using .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'd like to build a GATT client in .NET Core. It will deploy to a RPi3 running Raspbian Lite controlling multiple BLE devices. Is there currently support for Bluetooth LE in the .Net Core Framework (2.2 or 3 preview)?

I'm aware of an alternative using a UWP library on Windows 10 IoT on the RPi, but I'd prefer to run Raspbian Lite instead. Are there currently any other alternatives for such a stack?

Comment: It looks like ads but [Bluetooth Framework](https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm) supports Windows 10 IoT (.NET Core). There are console demos in the package. Unfortunately we did not test it on raspbian cause it uses some Windows related functions.

Comment: Thanks @MikePetrichenko for you response. I just tried Bluetooth Framework with no success.

First it needed libunwind.so.8, which I was able to install, but then it failed with an exception on a typical Windows library:

system.dllnotfoundexception: unable to load dll 'advapi32.dll

This could possibly be a hint to the library to resolve this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5737#issuecomment-175916673

Comment: Thank you for your try. I am not 100% sure but it looks possible to modify the lib to get iut working on your platform. Can you please sned me an e-mail to mike@btframework.com with your task description so I can try to remove advapi dependences and send you a test version? I will be able to do it in next couple of weeks if that is OK for you.

Comment: I have the same requirement too. Any idea to setup a gatt server on Raspbian with dotnet core?

Answer (score 32):

### Background

BlueZ is the Bluetooth stack on Linux. The BlueZ developers encourage the use of their high-level [D-Bus APIs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc). (Source: https://youtu.be/VMDyebKT5c4?t=2102 or https://elinux.org/images/3/32/Doing_Bluetooth_Low_Energy_on_Linux.pdf, slide 22.) D-Bus lets you control all sorts of system services, and there are D-Bus bindings/packages for lots of platforms including .Net Core. So it should be somewhat simple to write a GATT client or GATT server using .Net targeting Linux (e.g. Raspbian Lite).

### Solution

For .Net Core you can use [Tmds.DBus](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/09/18/connecting-net-core-d-bus/) to access D-Bus. Tmds.DBus comes with a tool to generate the C# interfaces for a D-Bus service. I used `bluetoothctl`, the BlueZ interactive command-line tool, to scan and connect to a BLE peripheral, and then used `dotnet dbus codegen --bus system --service org.bluez` to generate C# interfaces.

### Sample code

`dotnet dbus codegen` generated code excerpt:

```
[DBusInterface("org.bluez.Adapter1")]
interface IAdapter1 : IDBusObject
{
    Task StartDiscoveryAsync();
    Task SetDiscoveryFilterAsync(IDictionary<string, object> Properties);
    Task StopDiscoveryAsync();
    Task RemoveDeviceAsync(ObjectPath Device);
    Task<string[]> GetDiscoveryFiltersAsync();
    Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string prop);
    Task<Adapter1Properties> GetAllAsync();
    Task SetAsync(string prop, object val);
    Task<IDisposable> WatchPropertiesAsync(Action<PropertyChanges> handler);
}

[DBusInterface("org.bluez.Device1")]
interface IDevice1 : IDBusObject
{
    Task DisconnectAsync();
    Task ConnectAsync();
    Task ConnectProfileAsync(string UUID);
    Task DisconnectProfileAsync(string UUID);
    Task PairAsync();
    Task CancelPairingAsync();
    Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string prop);
    Task<Device1Properties> GetAllAsync();
    Task SetAsync(string prop, object val);
    Task<IDisposable> WatchPropertiesAsync(Action<PropertyChanges> handler);
}

[DBusInterface("org.bluez.GattService1")]
interface IGattService1 : IDBusObject
{
    Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string prop);
    Task<GattService1Properties> GetAllAsync();
    Task SetAsync(string prop, object val);
    Task<IDisposable> WatchPropertiesAsync(Action<PropertyChanges> handler);
}

[DBusInterface("org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1")]
interface IGattCharacteristic1 : IDBusObject
{
    Task<byte[]> ReadValueAsync(IDictionary<string, object> Options);
    Task WriteValueAsync(byte[] Value, IDictionary<string, object> Options);
    Task<(CloseSafeHandle fd, ushort mtu)> AcquireWriteAsync(IDictionary<string, object> Options);
    Task<(CloseSafeHandle fd, ushort mtu)> AcquireNotifyAsync(IDictionary<string, object> Options);
    Task StartNotifyAsync();
    Task StopNotifyAsync();
    Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string prop);
    Task<GattCharacteristic1Properties> GetAllAsync();
    Task SetAsync(string prop, object val);
    Task<IDisposable> WatchPropertiesAsync(Action<PropertyChanges> handler);
}
```

Example usage. Given a BLE peripheral address, connects and prints characteristic values for the "Device Information" GATT service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
// The code generated by `dotnet dbus codegen`.
using bluez.DBus;
// See https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/09/18/connecting-net-core-d-bus/ or https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.DBus
using Tmds.DBus;

// Use the `bluetoothctl` command-line tool or the Bluetooth Manager GUI to scan for devices and possibly pair.
// Then you can use this program to connect and print "Device Information" GATT service values.
class Program
{
  static string defaultAdapterName = "hci0";
  static TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

  static async Task Main(string[] args)
  {
    if (args.Length < 1)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Usage: BlueZExample <deviceAddress> [adapterName]");
      Console.WriteLine("Example: BlueZExample AA:BB:CC:11:22:33 hci1");
      return;
    }

    var deviceAddress = args[0];
    var adapterName = args.Length > 1 ? args[1] : defaultAdapterName;

    // Get the Bluetooth adapter.
    var adapterObjectPath = $"/org/bluez/{adapterName}";
    var adapter = Connection.System.CreateProxy<IAdapter1>(BluezConstants.DBusService, adapterObjectPath);
    if (adapter == null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Bluetooth adapter '{adapterName}' not found.");
    }

    // Find the Bluetooth peripheral.
    var device = await adapter.GetDeviceAsync(deviceAddress);
    if (device == null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Bluetooth peripheral with address '{deviceAddress}' not found. Use `bluetoothctl` or Bluetooth Manager to scan and possibly pair first.");
      return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Connecting...");
    await device.ConnectAsync();
    await WaitForPropertyValueAsync<bool>("Connected", device.GetConnectedAsync, value: true, timeout);
    Console.WriteLine("Connected.");

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for services to resolve...");
    await WaitForPropertyValueAsync<bool>("ServicesResolved", device.GetServicesResolvedAsync, value: true, timeout);

    var servicesUUID = await device.GetUUIDsAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"Device offers {servicesUUID.Length} service(s).");

    var deviceInfoServiceFound = servicesUUID.Any(uuid => String.Equals(uuid, GattConstants.DeviceInformationServiceUUID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    if (!deviceInfoServiceFound)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Device doesn't have the Device Information Service. Try pairing first?");
      return;
    }

    // Console.WriteLine("Retrieving Device Information service...");
    var service = await device.GetServiceAsync(GattConstants.DeviceInformationServiceUUID);
    var modelNameCharacteristic = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(GattConstants.ModelNameCharacteristicUUID);
    var manufacturerCharacteristic = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(GattConstants.ManufacturerNameCharacteristicUUID);

    int characteristicsFound = 0;
    if (modelNameCharacteristic != null)
    {
        characteristicsFound++;
        Console.WriteLine("Reading model name characteristic...");
        var modelNameBytes = await modelNameCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(timeout);
        Console.WriteLine($"Model name: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(modelNameBytes)}");
    }

    if (manufacturerCharacteristic != null)
    {
        characteristicsFound++;
        Console.WriteLine("Reading manufacturer characteristic...");
        var manufacturerBytes = await manufacturerCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(timeout);
        Console.WriteLine($"Manufacturer: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(manufacturerBytes)}");
    }

    if (characteristicsFound == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Model name and manufacturer characteristics not found.");
    }
  }

  static async Task WaitForPropertyValueAsync<T>(string propertyName, Func<Task<T>> action, T value, TimeSpan timeout)
  {
    // Ideally we'd wait for D-Bus PropertyChanged events to fire, but for now we'll poll.
    // Also ideally we'd be able to read property values for any D-Bus object, but for now we take a function.
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (watch.Elapsed <= timeout)
    {
      await Task.Delay(50);

      if ((await action()).Equals(value))
      {
        return;
      }
    }

    throw new TimeoutException($"Timed out waiting for {propertyName} to equal {value}.");
  }
}

// Extensions that make it easier to get a D-Bus object or read a characteristic value.
static class Extensions
{
  public static Task<IReadOnlyList<IDevice1>> GetDevicesAsync(this IAdapter1 adapter)
  {
    return GetProxiesAsync<IDevice1>(adapter, BluezConstants.Device1Interface);
  }

  public static async Task<IDevice1> GetDeviceAsync(this IAdapter1 adapter, string deviceAddress)
  {
    var devices = await GetProxiesAsync<IDevice1>(adapter, BluezConstants.Device1Interface);

    var matches = new List<IDevice1>();
    foreach (var device in devices)
    {
      if (String.Equals(await device.GetAddressAsync(), deviceAddress, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
          matches.Add(device);
      }
    }

    // BlueZ can get in a weird state, probably due to random public BLE addresses.
    if (matches.Count > 1)
    {
        throw new Exception($"{matches.Count} devices found with the address {deviceAddress}!");
    }

    return matches.FirstOrDefault();
  }

  public static async Task<IGattService1> GetServiceAsync(this IDevice1 device, string serviceUUID)
  {
    var services = await GetProxiesAsync<IGattService1>(device, BluezConstants.GattServiceInterface);

    foreach (var service in services)
    {
      if (String.Equals(await service.GetUUIDAsync(), serviceUUID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        return service;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  public static async Task<IGattCharacteristic1> GetCharacteristicAsync(this IGattService1 service, string characteristicUUID)
  {
    var characteristics = await GetProxiesAsync<IGattCharacteristic1>(service, BluezConstants.GattCharacteristicInterface);

    foreach (var characteristic in characteristics)
    {
      if (String.Equals(await characteristic.GetUUIDAsync(), characteristicUUID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        return characteristic;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  public static async Task<byte[]> ReadValueAsync(this IGattCharacteristic1 characteristic, TimeSpan timeout)
  {
    var options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var readTask = characteristic.ReadValueAsync(options);
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout);

    await Task.WhenAny(new Task[] { readTask, timeoutTask });
    if (!readTask.IsCompleted)
    {
      throw new TimeoutException("Timed out waiting to read characteristic value.");
    }

    return await readTask;
  }

  private static async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetProxiesAsync<T>(IDBusObject rootObject, string interfaceName)
  {
    // Console.WriteLine("GetProxiesAsync called.");
    var objectManager = Connection.System.CreateProxy<IObjectManager>(BluezConstants.DBusService, "/");
    var objects = await objectManager.GetManagedObjectsAsync();

    var matchingObjects = objects
      .Where(obj => obj.Value.Keys.Contains(interfaceName))
      .Select(obj => obj.Key)
      .Where(objectPath => objectPath.ToString().StartsWith($"{rootObject.ObjectPath}/"));

    var proxies = matchingObjects
      .Select(objectPath => Connection.System.CreateProxy<T>(BluezConstants.DBusService, objectPath))
      .ToList();

    // Console.WriteLine($"GetProxiesAsync returning {proxies.Count} proxies of type {typeof(T)}.");
    return proxies;
  }
}

static class GattConstants
{
  // "Device Information" GATT service
  // https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=244369
  public const string DeviceInformationServiceUUID = "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
  public const string ModelNameCharacteristicUUID = "00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
  public const string ManufacturerNameCharacteristicUUID = "00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
}

static class BluezConstants
{
  public const string DBusService = "org.bluez";
  public const string Adapter1Interface = "org.bluez.Adapter1";
  public const string Device1Interface = "org.bluez.Device1";
  public const string GattServiceInterface = "org.bluez.GattService1";
  public const string GattCharacteristicInterface = "org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1";
}
```

### NuGet Package

Based on the code above, I published [HashtagChris.DotNetBlueZ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HashtagChris.DotNetBlueZ), a quick attempt at a .Net Core library for BlueZ. It works on my Raspberry Pi (after [installing the 5.50 release of BlueZ](https://learn.adafruit.com/install-bluez-on-the-raspberry-pi)) and may be useful. However if you run into issues using the package I recommend trying to access the [BlueZ D-Bus APIs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc) directly. The [C source code for bluetoothctl](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/client) serves as a good example for how to use the D-Bus APIs to scan, connect, pair, etc.

Comment: Sweet! Nice finding this on my first google about this, and you posted an answer 18h ago! :-D

Comment: In my opinion one shouldn't need to use a third party lib for such a basic thing as connecting to a BLE device. That said, I'll definately give this a try! If it works,I'll accept this as the solution.

Comment: @RaymondBrink I think it is save to say, that .NET Core is not build with the idea of being a desktop or devices platform on Linux (unlike on Windows .NET Core or the .NET Framework). It might change with the advent of System.Maui (aka Xamarin Forms), but they already declared their Linux Support to be community driven. And even in Xamarin, the essential package does not include BLE.

Comment: How can I create a GATT server and advertise it using D-Bus on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @ParsaKarami Did you found a way to do that?, I'm currently working on something like that where I need to create a GATT server and advertise it in Raspberry Pi 4