# Bluetooth GATT server using D-Bus and .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, dbus

I am trying to run a Bluetooth GATT server on raspberry pi 3 and raspbian OS. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56623587/2758859), the BlueZ D-Bus api can be used in .Net Core by [Tmds.DBus](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/09/18/connecting-net-core-d-bus/) library and its C# interfaces can be generate using `Tmds.DBus` tool.
I have read Bluez docs and most of the existing samples (based on python and c),
but i can't understand how to define and advertise the GATT server in .Net Core.

Can anyone provide a .Net sample or any other solution?

Comment: What error are you getting?  The links you provided already have sample code so you must have an error.

Comment: @jdweng The sample in that post is about connecting to gatt service(its a gatt client), but i want to create and run a gatt server that expose a service (peripheral bluetooth mode).

Comment: the you want to develop you own cloud application that has two ports.  1)  A client that connects to the gatt service 2) One that is a Cloud Server application that accepts clients.  You are not creating a gatt service, just connecting to an exist service.

Comment: What do you mean about cloud app? each device in bluetooth LE connection can have two roles, client or server. the server exposes some services and characteristics and the client device can connect and use those services.

Comment: Cloud App is a server.  You want a webpage (server) that clients can connect and will communicate with the Tmds Library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a BLE peripheral is one of the more tricky things to do with BlueZ D-Bus API. You will need to create a GATT server and an advertisement. Unlike the GATT client, creating the server requires for objects to be registered on the dbus.

I am not familiar with .NET, but it is the ability to register objects in D-Bus is the key to getting a GATT server working. From this [example](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.DBus/blob/master/docs/howto.md) I found the key word is : `RegisterObjectAsync`

Using that keyword, I then did a search and turned up this library as using it:

https://github.com/phylomeno/dotnet-ble-server

This looks like it should be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ukBaz, i test the library and it worked perfectly.